# Peano space is a continuous image of the unit interval I

Tags: general-topology

A Hausdorff space $X$ is a Peano space if it is a continuous image of the unit interval $I$

**Definition :- A Peano space is a compact, connected, locally connected metric space.**

update :-

$I$ is is a compact, connected and the continuous image of it is so .

How I can start with locally connected metric space ?

Comment: You can start from the definition of Peano space

Comment: Hint: what are you know about $I$ ? And the continuous image of it ?

Comment: please, see  my update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f$ be a continuous map of $I$ onto $X$.

$X$ must be compact and metric.

Moreover, $X$ is the continuous image of a connected space and a quotient of a locally connected space, so $X$ has these 
properties itself.

Thus, $X$ is a Peano space.

(To see this, let $H$ be closed in $I$, then $H$ is compact, so $f(H)$ is also compact.

Now, $f(H)$ is compact in a Hausdorff space $X$, hence $f(H)$ is closed. Therefore, $f$ is a quotient map).

Comment: Why is it metrisable? It's true, but it needs a reason/theorem.

Comment: what do you mean??

Comment: You say let $f$ be a continuous map of $I$ onto $X$ (only assumed to Hausdorff). Then you say "$X$ must be compact and metric". Which is true,  it follows from this $f$, except replace "metric" by "metrisable", and give a reason for the it.

Comment: Also, locally connected is not immediate (but true).

Answer (score 4):

This is the easy part of the Hahn-Mazurkiewicz theorem. So I had some fun tracking references inside Willard:

Suppose $f: [0,1] \to X$ is continuous and onto, where $X$ is a Hausdorff topological space.

- Willard Thm. 17.7 (cont. image of compact is compact) implies that $X$ is compact because $[0,1]$ is compact (example 17.9, it's closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}$).
- 26.3 (continuous image of connected is connected) implies that $X$ is connected. Example 26.2c says $[0,1]$ is connected.
- $f$ is a quotient map because it is a closed map (see proof of 17.14)
- So 27.12 then implies, because $f$ is quotient, that $X$ is locally connected.
- Corollary 23.2 (of Urysohn's metrisation theorem) says that a continuous image of a compact metric space inside a Hausdorff space is metrisable. So $X$ is metrisable.

Putting all together we see that $X$ is a Peano space.

Comment: I think that you can use this instead of the last point.
Theorem:The continuous image of compact metric is compact metric

Comment: @HamadaAl I already quoted a more accurate version in the last point. You do need the Hausdorff part (if you map to an indiscrete space or cofinite space, the result is non-metrisable.